# how to archive specific files from the different directories?

Tags: linux, search, find, archive, tar

Actually I have a file in my linux that is very important to me, the name of this file is `yz.tmp` So, I want to search all directories and archive them,how is it possible ?

first I find all of them via this command :

```
find . -name "yz.tmp"
```

now how can I archive them without directory? like this:

```
yz01.tmp
yz02.tmp
.
.
.
yz100.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

This appends the files one by one to an uncompressed tar archive `test.tar`:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for file in $(find . -name 'yz.tmp'); do
  NEW_NAME=$(printf "yz%03d.tmp" $i)
  tar rf test.tar --transform "s,.*,$NEW_NAME," "$file"
  i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Using `--transform` renames the files on-the-fly into your desired format. Be aware that this won't work with compressed tar archives.

Comment: Dear @nif thnx for your help , but it doesn't work for me ,after I run it , nothing happened, why?